# How to create new table and insert using function in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want  to create a function in plsql to create table dynamically

```
   Create or replace procedure p_dynamic_table (p_table varchar2, 
    col_specs varchar2)
    as
    sql_stmt varchar2 (2000);
    begin
       sql_stmt := 'CREATE TABLE' || p_table || '(' || col_specs || ')';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
    end;
```

Comment: What's the question, then? That should do the trick, as long as the col_specs column is valid. 

Another question: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Steven, there is a space missing after the word ...TABLE'.  Agree on the "why?" question.

Comment: i am learning pl/sql ,trainer gave me this question

Answer (score 3):

Put a space after TABLE and before the ending single quote.

Then your procedure will "work". It will not be a function, but a procedure. Also, it is a procedure that has no added value so I don't understand why you want to code it.

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. could you please elaborate how to create table and columns  using function in pl/sql?

Comment: No I can't, because you don't say what the function should return. Please elaborate as to why you want a function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to create Procedure or Function?

You mentioned Function in Topics header but try to create Procedure (according the mentioned code by you).

If you don't want to create constraints & Indexes then your Procedure is okay without

> SQL_STMT := 'CREATE TABLE' || P_TABLE || '(' || COL_SPECS || ')';

you must be put SPACE after 'CREATE TABLE' which is already mentioned in answer of Stew Ashton.

According to what I understood, I tried to mention the solution below.

**PROCEDURE**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_DYNAMIC_TABLE (P_TABLE      VARCHAR2,
                                                 COL_SPECS    VARCHAR2)
    AS
       SQL_STMT   VARCHAR2 (2000);
    BEGIN
       SQL_STMT := 'CREATE TABLE ' || P_TABLE || '(' || COL_SPECS || ')';

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STMT;
    END P_DYNAMIC_TABLE;
```

**Execute Procedure**

```
    EXEC P_DYNAMIC_TABLE('TEST_TBL','COLUMN_1 NUMBER , COLUMN_2 VARCHAR2(100), COLUMN_3 DATE');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this!

```
create or replace procedure f2
is
begin
execute immediate 'create table &nds_ddl(&c1 &datatype)';
end;
```

Then execute the procedure f2
i.e

```
exec f2;


Select * from table_name_you_entered;
```